# Get an input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, input, getch

I'm writing a terminal game. It rewrites the game field every second. I want a user to interact by pressing a key. Here is a simplified example of what I came up with:

```
require 'io/console'

move = true

thr = Thread.new do
  while move do
    puts "Foo"
    sleep(1)
  end
end

loop do
  input = $stdin.getch
  if input == "a"
    move = false
    break
  end
end
```

Looks like it works. But I have a strange output from `thr`, which messes up the entire game field:

[image: game field]

Comment: If you're making a game you might want to use the [`curses`](https://github.com/ruby/curses) library and have an event loop that checks the readable status of your keyboard. There's no reason for threads here.

Comment: How to do correct output by a thread?

Comment: When I tried your code, the "Foo" is always written at the beginning of the line, not inserted as in your case. This is likely because of a difference in the terminal settings. `puts` writes a line feed at the end of the string, and the terminal you are using, interprets the line feed as a, well, line feed. How is the output, when you write `puts "Foo\r"` ?

Comment: user1934428 puts "Foo\r" works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`puts` automatically appends a newline (`\n`) after outputting the string to the screen. This is useful in most cases, but not always.

Use `print` if you don't want a newline:

```
print "Foo"
```

In this case, you probably also want to clear the existing line; you can do that with `\r` (for "carriage return"):

```
print "Foo\r"
```

This will move the cursor back to column 0. Be aware that it will *not* clear any characters − it merely moves the cursor back to column 0 so it can override characters. So for example this:

```
print "Hello\r"
print "Foo\r"
```

Will result in:

```
Foolo
```

Since `Foo` only outputs three characters − two less than those on the screen. To fix that, we need to add spaces:

```
print "Foo  \r"
```

There's also `\b` (backspace) to move the cursor one character back:

```
print "Foo"
print "\b\bee"
```

will result in:

```
Fee
```

All of this is rather tedious to work with, and exactly the reason why the [`curses`](https://github.com/ruby/curses) library exists ;-) It wraps all of this in wrapper functions which deal with erasing the correct stuff and it was originally developed for ASCII games like this ;-) I recommend you use it!

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Carriage return solved my issue. I guess next time I'll use curses library. Would be great to have some tutorial for that.